# WP7 overlapping images

Tags: windows-phone-7, canvas, silverlight-toolkit, overlap, overlapping

I tried to place a photo frame (image) on a picture using code

```
<Canvas>
   <Image x:Name="picture" Source="{Binding XXX}" Canvas.ZIndex="1">
       <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <MatrixTransform x:Name="previousTransform" />
                <TransformGroup x:Name="currentTransform">
                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform" />
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform" />
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="translateTransform" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </TransformGroup>
       </Image.RenderTransform>

                <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                        <toolkit:GestureListener DragStarted="OnGestureListenerDragStarted" DragDelta="OnGestureListenerDragDelta" DragCompleted="OnGestureListenerDragCompleted" PinchStarted="OnGestureListenerPinchStarted" PinchDelta="OnGestureListenerPinchDelta" PinchCompleted="OnGestureListenerPinchCompleted"/>
                    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            </Image>

   <Image x:Name="photoframe" Source="{Binding XXX}" Canvas.ZIndex="2"/>
</Canvas>
```

But it seems that the gestureService is no longer working if I overlap these two photoes using above code.

What I want is that placing a photo frame over a picture but no losing the gesture control (dragging or pinching the picture).

Thanks.

Comment: i would suggest you to create a new style or template fot the image and maybe that solves your problem :) Or try to set hittestvisibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The photoframe is capturing the touch events of your image, because it is on top of your
image. If you set the gestureservice on the photoframe, it will work again. Maybe setting
the IsHitTestVisible of the photoframe to false will solves your problem too (I never tested it).

Greets